# Nodal Analysis in AC with different Frequency throughout

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am trying to solve this circuit for the voltage across nodes C and D. Now I think I know how to solve it mostly and would probably opt for loop analysis.  But what has me confused is that the current supply is operating at 3r/s while the voltage supply is operating at 5r/s

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7ey6i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The ground I can place anywhere I want but I figured the place it is in the diagram made the most sense.

Is there some simple rule I am forgetting on converting frequency so that I can more easily calculate the resistance of the inductors and capacitors?  If not how would I go about calculating the resistance of inductors and capacitors with two different 'w' in the circuit?

Comment: Did you cover super-position yet?

Comment: Ahh of course. Yes we did but I did not think of it. Than you!

Comment: Maybe you can answer your own question officially. That is done periodically. Not frowned upon or "illegal."

Comment: Once I work it out tomorrow morning and verify I fully understand it I will do just that.

Answer (score 1):

This becomes very simple with superposition.  Just solve for the voltage at the required nodes using only one source at a time.  Then add them up and you should have the answer.